# Is there a good reference book on allegories used in literature?

Tags: creative-writing, resources, rhetoric

Is there a good reference book on allegories used in literature? I am looking for a reference book that gives references to use of allegories in the creative literature. For example: If a novel uses the allegory of "Adam and Eve", I would like an entry with the name of the book and how the allegory is conveyed, which objects represent which object from the allegory and so on. Is there such a book? I have been trying to find such a book with no luck.

Comment: **Reminder to those answering:** Link only answer are discouraged and may be deleted. Please include relevant information about the resources you are recommending, what makes that resource a good answer to the question? do you have experience with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on this. 
[Encyclopedia of Allegorical Literature (ABC-CLIO Literary Companion)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0874367816)

- **Author**:  David Adams Leeming; Kathleen Morgan Drowne
- **Publisher**:   Santa Barbara, Calif. : ABC-CLIO, ©1996.
- **Series**:  ABC-CLIO literary companion.
- **Edition**/Format:    Print book : English
- **Summary**: "*In the Encyclopedia of Allegorical Literature, readers will find more than 400 concise articles covering all aspects of literary allegory: the device wherein characters, situations, and actions stand for ideas. Far-ranging in scope, the book covers the entire Western allegorical tradition during the vast sweep of time between the Old Testament Song of Songs and the postmodernist novels of Thomas Pynchon and Ishmael Reed. Selected Indian, Middle Eastern, South American, and African works are also included, as are works that are not, strictly speaking, allegories, yet contain allegorical aspects. In addition, the authors provide articles on allegory as it relates to film, music, psychoanalysis, and other fields." "The A-to-Z entries include allegorical works, authors, characters, definitions, and literary devices and terms, all carefully cross-referenced to direct the reader to related topics. Essays on the works include a brief overview of the work itself as well as an analysis of how closely it adheres to the definition of allegory set out in the helpful introduction. Quick-reference appendixes list titles of works featured in the book both alphabetically and chronologically. An extensive bibliography refers readers to a wealth of background material. A subject index rounds out the volume.*"

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20091)

Comment: @linksassin Edited and added details as much as I know. Hope it is better now.

Comment: Copy pasting the description of the book doesn't really make it less of a link only answer. Have you read the book you are recommending? What makes it a good answer to the question? Ideally we want answer based on experience not links to google results. This might be a perfect answer to the question but it's impossible to know without following the link and reading the book.